# Hide part of stored procedure and resultset data columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security, stored-procedures, encryption

I want to hide some part of my stored procedures even when a user uses `sp_helptext`. Because I want to maintain some security purposes.

I even wanted to hide some of the data columns in the result set of the stored procedure.

Comment: There is no solid way to prevent a user from viewing the content of your stored procedures. You can use with encryption but it is trivial to get around it. If you want to protect your code you need to create a webservice and store the data externally. But honestly, there shouldn't be that much logic in your sql anyway. I have seen this request a lot over the years and there has never been anything actually worth protecting. And hiding columns in the result set makes no sense at all. If you don't want the data visible, don't return it.

Comment: In addition to Sean's comments... If I were looking to buy a 3rd party application (with SQL Server as the back end), I'd automatically disqualify any product that tried to obfuscate any part of the SQL schema or code.